# Designing MVC Crud with Modal problem (Not allow direct acess to Create action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I´m have a Car View with a list of car... So, I have a Create button that opens a Modal (UI JQuery Dialog) with Site/Car/Create content...

All works fine... But I´d like to block direct access to : Site/Car/Create...

Is that possible? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really possible to block it completely, but you can do some things to make it more difficult.  First, require that it come from a POST request.  That will prevent someone from simply entering the URL with request parameters.  Second, use the antiforgery token helper.  That will help prevent a third-party from doing a POST to the url since they will also require both the token input and the token cookie.  Third, you could potentially check if the request has the X-HTTP-REQUESTED-WITH header and only do the POST (or GET) via AJAX.  It's not that hard to get around but it would prevent an accidental access if you do use GET.  Fourth, and it probably should have been first, make sure that only authorized users have access to the action using the AuthorizeAttribute.  Fifth, use SSL to prevent unauthorized access using FireSheep and protect your cookies and data from snooping.

In short, you won't be able to prevent a determined person with legitimate authorization from crafting a request to the action if they a really want to without using your interface.  They can always craft a request that will look exactly like the one you would send.   You can make it more difficult and prevent accidental access, though, using the above methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
     }
}
```

And then stick on your Create action like this:

```
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult Create()
{
   ...etc
}
```